# Is it possible to put a method in thread without onclick?

Tags: android, multithreading, button

Everywhere I've seen, they have used Threading with onClick. Now i am kind of forced to use Threading as i can not perform a networking operation on its main thread as documentation says. So how would i put The threading on a button that i have coded something like this?

```
public void firstbutton(View view) 
{
//some code
}
```

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:**

```
        public void firstbutton(View view) 
    {
        InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        inputMgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);

        EditText idnumber=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String idnumber2= idnumber.getText().toString();
        int i = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
        idnum=i;
        setContentView(R.layout.viewer);
        Context context = view.getContext();
        Drawable image = ImageOperations(context, WEB ADDRESS HIDDEN FOR PRIVACY"+idnumber2);
        ImageView icon = new ImageView(context);
        icon = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        icon.setImageDrawable(image);
};


public Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
        return d;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException
{
URL url = new URL(address);
Object content = url.getContent();
return content;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve.

If you just want to start a new thread for your networking stuff, you can use the `Thread` method like this:

```
public void firstbutton(View view) 
{
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do your network stuff
        }
    }.start();
}
```

If you need to update the UI once the network operation is done, `AsyncTask` is probably a better choice:

```
    new AsyncTask<Void,Void,ResultType>() {
        @Override
        protected ResultType doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Do network stuff
            return someResult;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ResultType result) {
            // Update UI with your result
        };
    };
```

Comment: That is the standard Java way - I also first thought in that direction. But as we are on Android may be a [android.os.AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) may be more suitable?

Comment: Both are working fine. AsyncTask is just bringing some convenient and clear typing...

Comment: Totally agree. Using the `Thread` class is sometimes just enough (more readable/light than AsyncTask)

Comment: I tried doing it myself, but i didnt put run in there. I was getting a little lost. Thank you soo much!

Comment: I just entered the part where i believe i am running into the network error. I was trying to put in the new thread, but had many errors, because it did not recognize the objects instantiated in there. I also tried AsyncTask, but it also gave me a billion other errors. Is there anything specific that i have to do to put it in?

Answer (score 0):

Well, exactly the same way you would do inside an onClick() method.

I assume (tell me if I'm wrong) that your `firstbutton()` method is called when your button is clicked (thus I's run by onClick())

Do, you can write :

```
public void firstbutton(View view) {
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
            // Do your network stuff
     }).start();
}
```

(or you can use AsyncTask class as usual too...)